Issue while transfering file with httpurlconnection
I have the following error while transfering a file from a presigned-url (GET) to an other one (PUT). I happends when call my API more than 3 time in parallele.
For example, if i call it 10 times. 3 Transfer will be done in 1 minutes and then the CPU usage will drop to 0 in my POD monitoring and I will get the error 15 minutes later.
    java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.checkError(HttpURLConnection.java:3807)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.write(HttpURLConnection.java:3789)
...
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Suppressed: java.io.IOException: insufficient data written
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.close(HttpURLConnection.java:3834)
    at .....
    ... 3 more

My method :
public ResponseEntity<String> transferData(Config config) throws IOException {

var inputUrl = config.getInputdUrl();
var outputUrl = config.getOutputdUrl();


var uploadConnection = uploader.getUploadConnection(outputUrl);

try (var inputStream = downloader.getDownloadConnection(inputUrl).getInputStream(); 
     var outputStream = uploadConnection.getOutputStream()) {

    IOUtils.copyLarge(inputStream, outputStream);
    outputStream.flush();
    var resp = uploadConnection.getResponseCode();

    return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.OK)
            .body("Transfer done with response:" + resp);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .body("An  error occurred while transferring data : " + ioe);
}

}
And I am calling this method in a springboot controller by doing :
            new Thread(() -> transferDataToScality(...)).start();
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Downloading data in asynchronous mode successfully started");

How can i avoid having this issue ?

Try what happens if you call the API from three separate Java processes. If it still causes errors the problem is not the client but the server code.

There is no response as long as you haven’t finished writing to the uploadConnection.  Close your streams before you examine the response code:
try (var inputStream = downloader.getDownloadConnection(inputUrl).getInputStream(); 
     var outputStream = uploadConnection.getOutputStream()) {

    IOUtils.copyLarge(inputStream, outputStream);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .body("An  error occurred while transferring data : " + ioe);
}

var resp = uploadConnection.getResponseCode();

return ResponseEntity
        .status(HttpStatus.OK)
        .body("Transfer done with response:" + resp);

Notice I removed the call to outputStream.flush().  It is not needed, since closing an InputStream or OutputStream always flushes it.
You also don’t need a third-party class like IOUtils.  Just use transferTo:
try (var inputStream = downloader.getDownloadConnection(inputUrl).getInputStream(); 
     var outputStream = uploadConnection.getOutputStream()) {

    inputStream.transferTo(outputStream);
} catch (IOException ioe) {


Even with those change, i still have the same error/behaviour
